# C++ 11, Reading characters from a stringstream returns last character twice

Tags: stringstream

So I'm reading from a stringstream character by character because I want to copy its content into another string in a specific format, the problem is that for some reason I get the last character of the stream to be copied twice. Here's the code

```
string infoTabella;
while(ss >> noskipws  >> c){
    if(c==44||c==40||c==41) {
        infoTabella += ' ';
        infoTabella += c;
        infoTabella += ' ';
    }else{
        infoTabella += c;
    }
}
```

shouldn't the while condition be set to false when I reach the end of the stream?

(sorry for bad English, not my first language)

Comment: mention how other variables(c, ss) are defined

Comment: c is just a character (char c;), ss is a stringstream (stringstream ss) to which I attached (ss.str(query)) a string called query with this content :"ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, NAME TEXT NOT NULL, AGE INT NOT NULL, ADDRESS TEXT, COUNTRY_ID INT, SALARY FLOAT,PRIMARY KEY(ID) FOREIGN KEY (COUNTRY_ID) REFERENCES COUNTRIES (ID)", the result I'm getting is (in infoTabella): "ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  NAME TEXT NOT NULL ,  AGE INT NOT NULL ,  ADDRESS TEXT ,  COUNTRY_ID INT ,  SALARY FLOAT , PRIMARY KEY ( ID )  FOREIGN KEY  ( COUNTRY_ID )  REFERENCES COUNTRIES  ( ID )  ) "

Comment: damn I have the same issue!